# Adding a latitude/longitude graticule in CartoDB (e.g. WMS)

Tags: carto, latitude-longitude, basemap, grids-graticules

I'd like to add a basemap that has a graticule in latitude/ longitude to the Map View of a CartoDB project.  This could be in the WMS format for example, but I haven't been able to find one that works.

For my ArcMAP work, I first tried this NOAA WMS link, but got an "unspecified error" message. When I tried it in CartoBD, I get options for 1, 5 and 10 degree, but these end up with a blank background.

http://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/arcgis/services/graticule/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

I can email NOAA about the error, but ideally, I would prefer a satellite or terrain basemap that has lat/longs included in the map.  So, I thought I'd ask the forum first.

For example, I have an ArcGIS server link from NOAA that works great in ArcMAP:  GIS Servers\arcgis on maps.ngdc.noaa.gov\arctic with many layers of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find graticules here:

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-physical-vectors/

and add them as a new layer.